# Is there any way to press the I and II buttons without the touch screen?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, zelda-ocarina-of-time

There are only two buttons (X and Y) that are mappable in the 3DS version of Ocarina of Time. There are two more, labeled I and II, that can be used via the touch screen. The touch screen, however, is really inconvenient to use in the heat of battle. So far I've been coping by putting non-combat items on I and II, but now I have three combat items I'd like to have equipped at once.

Is there any more convenient way to interact with items mapped to I or II besides the touch screen?

Comment: I don't think you can... I usually put the combat item requiring the least aiming on II, which is bomb. I can throw them with A anyway, once I activated it.

Comment: Oh that's a good tip about throwing bombs with A! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, unfortunately.  I and II are only available on the touch screen.